# how to get back certain values from a single ID HttpClient webservice query

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api, uwp, httpclient

When I run the following code, I get back 0 on all results accept for uriD, which correctly resolves to http://localhost:2463/api/Devices/101070701. I can view these results from the web browser but not from inside of my app.

Full Discloser, I do get back all results inside of my app for other tables that I'm querying, but those are always LIST results. I have added that one below the zero results query.

**Zero Results Query**

```
            var uriD = new Uri("http://localhost:2463/api/Devices/" + HostName);
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        var devices = new Device()
        {
            HostName = HostName,
            DriveSN = DriveSN,
            IP = IP,
            Hardware = Hardware
        };

        try
        {

            var JsonResponseD = await client.GetStringAsync(uriD);
            var devicesResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Device>(JsonResponseD);
            devices = devicesResult;
        }
```

**Successful Query**

```
        var uriC = new Uri("http://localhost:2463/api/Contacts");                    
        var JsonResponseC = await client.GetStringAsync(uriC);
        var contactsResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Contact>>(JsonResponseC);
            Contacts = contactsResult;
```

**JSON Response** for Single Device

```
{"HostName":101070701,"RouterName":"Test01RA","DriveModel":"Samsung","DriveSN":"123456789","OldDriveSN":"987654321","Server":true,"IP":"10.1.1.1","Gateway":"10.1.1.254","Hardware":"AzureVM","PinPadIP":"10.0.0.100","PreHostName":"PreHost01","EMV":true,"HardwareRole":"Main Register"}
```

[image: **Interface Image**]

Comment: Provide the content of `JsonResponseD` to see what you are trying deserialize

Comment: Ok... I added the single entry that can be resolved via browser at http://localhost:2463/api/Devices/101070701.

Comment: Are you getting list as a response?

Comment: I currently am not because I'm only wanting to show one value not a list.. so I didn't know best way to do it.. I've added a screenshot of rough interface is looking like so far. You will see a lot of X:Bind values that dont correspond to Device Info I'm asking about in post. That is because some I've already resolved, like Contacts, but the others are being pulled from other tables(5 to be exact) and I will need to do the same as with the Device Info.

Comment: Can you provide full json response, not only for a single device?

Answer (score 0):

Where I went wrong, I didn't have my properties set, so they had nothing to return..

Getting no results. Properties looked like this..

```
       public int HostName { get; set; }
```

After I resolved it, they looked like this..

```
       private int _HostName;
       public int HostName { get { return _HostName; } set { Set(ref _HostName, value); } }
```